# domain group members cannot access in TFS 2018

Tags: permissions, dns

In TFS2010, domain group member can access the collection for working. However, after upgrade to TFS2018, the domain group member failed to access.

The following seems the reason of domain group member cannot access the collection.

In TFS2010, a domain group (e.g. TeamA) was granted to TFS group (e.g. Project Collection Build Administrators) in collection, when the domain group (TeamA) was drill down to see the members, TFS can show the domain group members (e.g. John, Peter, ... etc) as below:
([screen cap of TFS2010 of domain member can be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaaDi.png)))

However, after upgraded to TFS2018, the same domain group (TeamA) seems cannot be recognized by TFS, when drill down to see the domain group members, TFS cannot show the domain group members (John, Peter ... etc), it showed empty list as below:
([screen cap of TFS2018 of domain member cannot be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgcO3.png))

TFS2010 in Server A, TFS2018 in Server B, TFS2010 was backup and restored in Server B to upgrade to TFS2015 and then finally upgraded to TFS2018. Both server has joined the same domain. Is TFS2018 behaviour change on the domain group support or something need to set in TFS2018 in order to get it works as TFS2010?

Currently, as a workaround, a local windows group in created in the Windows of Server B TFS2018. All the domain members is added to the local windows group and then the local windows group in granted to access the TFS group. Although this work fine but if there is member added, both the domain group and local group need to be updated. It would be better to make TFS2018 work as in TFS2010.

Comment: What specific error are people encountering? Have you checked event logs on the app tier server to see if a job is failing? Are you using the same service account for your app tier as you had used previously?

Comment: @DanielMann, thanks for the suggestion, when checking the service account to start Server A and Server B, found that Server A start by "Network Service" and Server B start by local Administrator. After change the start up account for the service "Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent" and add back the "Network Service"  system account to access the SQL Server TFS database, the issue has been solved.